# Issues with Spreadsheet::Read

Tags: perl, spreadsheet

In my application, we are using Spreadsheet::Read to read a excel and perform some task on the rows and finally add it to a database.

The file we are importing is an Excel file ( .XLSX). This excel file is actually a glossary which serves support to different user languages.

The problem, I am facing with this process is we have special character cells in some of the rows/columns which are not getting decoded correctly.

For example, if i have a SPANISH Excel FIle:

---

### *IN THE EXCEL SHEET*    => *Extract from the logs*

---

Información de cuenta                           => Informaci\x{f3}n de cuenta

Página de consola de administración de curso    => P\x{e1}gina de consola de administraci\x{f3}n de curso

Informaci\x{f3}n de cuenta is getting added in the Db and when fetched it is displaying extraneous characters in the UI.

I tried this solution but it is not working. this is basically Hacking of Spreadsheet::Read

```
use Text::Iconv;
package Spreadsheet::XLSX;

sub new {
    my $converter = Text::Iconv->new("ASCII","utf-8");
    return __PACKAGE__->SUPER::new(@_, $converter);
}
```

Please suggest me what is wrong or any better solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spreadsheet::Read returns strings as octets encoded in Latin1. To make Perl characters, use the [Encode](http://p3rl.org/Encode) module. Read the [introduction to the topic of encoding in Perl](http://p3rl.org/UNI).

```
use Encode qw(decode);
use Spreadsheet::Read qw(ReadData);
my $ref = ReadData 'spanish.xls';
my $characters = decode 'Latin-1', $ref->[1]{A1};
```

Comment: Does Spreadsheet::Read return strings as octets encoded in Latin1 even if the source file is UTF-8?